# Creating custom "player-objects"

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, customization

I'm looking for a way to create "player-objects" that are then all displayed on one page. They should just contain a few text-datafields with the players name, role and an image. Since I'm very new to wordpress, I have trouble finding anything that fits what I need.
The plan is to list the players on a "roster"-page  for the specific game they play, so a "game"-category would be helpful for sorting them.

Edit: I have trouble describing what exactly I'm searching for, I will provide further info if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For players you could create a [custom post type](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/), like so

```
function my_player_cpt() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Players', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Player', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
  );  
  $args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'taxonomies'         => array('game')
    'supports'           => array( 
      'title', // player name
      'thumbnail', // player image
      'excerpt' // player role
    ),
  );
  register_post_type( 'player', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'my_player_cpt');
```

The excerpt field could be used to save the player role. Other option could be a [custom meta field](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/).

And games could probably be [custom taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/),

```
function my_game_taxonomy() {
  $args = array(
    'label'        => __( 'Game', 'textdomain' ),
    'public'       => true,
  );   
  register_taxonomy( 'game', 'player', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'my_game_taxonomy');
```

To have the post type and taxonomy theme independent you should put the above code into a [custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/). That way the content stays visible in the WP admin even if you ever change your theme.

Then in your theme directory create a `taxonomy-game.php` [template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) and add your roster page code to it. Simple loop example below.

```
<?php 
// taxonomy-game.php
get_header();

if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="player">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>

      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

      <span><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Navigation ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php // No Posts Found ?>

<?php 
endif; 

get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Looks like I forgot to leave a comment! This is exactly what I needed, sorry for the late response & thank you very much :)